# changing 4th number in a version

Tags: c#, regex

I have a simple program that changes the third number an an assembly version file      that looks like this

```
 static void Main()
{
    string file = "AssemblyInfo.cs";
    if (File.Exists(file))
        File.WriteAllText(file,
            Regex.Replace(
                File.ReadAllText(file),
                @"(?<=\[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion\(""[0-9]*.[0-9]*.)[0-9]*(?=.[0-9]*""\)\])",
                m => (Convert.ToInt16(m.Value) + 1).ToString()
            )
        );
    }
}
```

What I would like to do instead is change the 4th number of that version instead.
 For example I want to change 1.3.4.9 to 1.3.4.10 by calling c# app.

Issue is I can't get the regular expression to pick that out and update.   There is a reason I am trying to use this approach so I would like to know how to update the reg. ex or other approach using c# code itself rather than have suggestions on other ways to do this.    Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
@"(?<=\[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion\(""[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.)[0-9]*(?=""\)\])"
```

Basically it does the same as your current regex, except it changes to match the 4th number. It has look behind to find the first 3 numbers, then matches the 4th number and looks forward for '`")]`'.

You should now be able to replace with your new number.

BTW: You can replace `'[0-9]'` with `'\d'`, if you like it shorter.